# ShowDialogue not generating DialogueResult.OK

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm writing a program that's supposed to download something off GitHub. It has a link to a raw file on GitHub. I'm using `DownloadDataAsync` to download it, and I have a progress bar to track how far it is in the download. It always gets to 100%, but then it does nothing.

I've been following a tutorial for a C# updater by BetterCoder (The beginning starts [here](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2Fn7btY&redir_token=tEWd8EJYNaaIR7wY0WgDfKu2qCd8MTQyNjk5MzQ5MkAxNDI2OTA3MDky) and the most relevant part would be Part 9 of the series).

This is the part where it stops working properly:

```
private void DownloadUpdate(SaveyourUpdateXML update)
{
    SharpUpdateDownloadForm form = new SharpUpdateDownloadForm(update.Uri, update.MD5, this.applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon);
    Debug.WriteLine("form created");
    DialogResult result = form.ShowDialog(this.applicationInfo.Context);
    Debug.WriteLine("got result");

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        String currentPath = this.applicationInfo.ApplicationAssembly.Location;
        String newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentPath) + "\\" + update.FileName;

        UpdateApplication(form.TempFilePath, currentPath, newPath, update.LaunchArgs);

        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

It never gets to the "got result" part unless I cancel it. Also, this.applicationInfo.Context returns a form. However, it does say "form created".

I think there's something wrong with the way ShowDialog is used or something, but I'm not really sure what.

**Edit:** This is what happens when a SharpUpdateDownloadForm is created.

```
internal SharpUpdateDownloadForm(Uri location, String md5, Icon programIcon)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (programIcon != null)
    {
        this.Icon = programIcon;
    }

    tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    this.md5 = md5;
    webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);

    bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

    try
    {
        webClient.DownloadDataAsync(location, this.tempFile);
    }

    catch
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

This is what should happen when a download is completed:

```
private void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
        this.Close();
    }
    else if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort;
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        lblProgress.Text = "Verifying Download...";
        progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;

        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new string[] {this.tempFile, this.md5});
    }
}
```

This is bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted

```
private void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = (DialogResult)e.Result;
    this.Close();
}
```

And bgWorker_DoWork

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        String file = ((string[])e.Argument)[0];
        String updateMD5 = ((string[])e.Argument)[1];

        if (Hasher.HashFile(file, HashType.MD5) != updateMD5)
            e.Result = DialogResult.No;
        else
            e.Result = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us how your code is closing/hiding `SharpUpdateDownloadForm` when a download is complete. That is where your problem is, not in the code you posted.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think I've added what you asked for. I'm not really sure if that's the right thing. I might just be missing it completely. I'm relatively new to C# programming.

Comment: So the file is downloaded completely, and lblProgress showing "Verifying Download...", and then you start the `bgWorker` to verify the file, right? What do you do in bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted? Do you close the `SharpUpdateDownloadForm` in bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted?

Comment: Somewhere you (should) be doing `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` That is the code we want to see.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I added some more information regarding my program. I think I have the equivalent of this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK but I'm not really sure. I actually copied the e.Result stuff from the tutorial so I figured it would work though I wasn't 100% sure that it would work. Right now, I think it's going to get the result into e.Result and then since it casts it back to a DialogueResult it should work properly after the ShowDialogue

Comment: @user3370201 OK, so is the line `e.Result = DialogResult.OK;` hit? If yes, you need to close the form manually or by code so the next line ("got result") can be executed, or the downloading form is still open and idle.

Comment: @kennyzx It's not being hit. I put a Debug.WriteLine statement at the beginning of bgWorker_DoWork and it didn't show up. However, I think bgWorker_DoWork is being called at the line that says bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork); and I put a Debug.WriteLine statement after that and it does hit that one. Did I do something wrong? I think none of the Event Handlers are working.

Comment: `bgWorker.DoWork +=...` does not start the bgWorker, it just register a delegate (things to be done by bgWorker), you start the bgWorker in this line `bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new string[] {this.tempFile, this.md5});`, if this line is run, I have no idea why `bgWorker_DoWork` is not executed.

Comment: @kennyzx That line does not get run. It looks like it doesn't detect completing the file download. webClient_DownloadProgressChanged gets called, however webClient_DownloadFileCompleted does not. This means that it wouldn't get to run the bgWorker stuff, so any idea why it wouldn't complete the download? The progress bar does get to 100%.

Comment: OH! Finally! When `webClient.DownloadDataAsync` completes, it fires `WebClient.DownloadDataCompleted` event, not `DownloadFileCompleted` - the one you registered.

Comment: @kennyzx So do I just need to change it to to webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadDataCompleted); and then rename the function webClient_DownloadFileCompleted to webClient_DownloadDataCompleted?

Comment: @user3370201 see my answer, it can solve the problem that `DownloadFileCompleted` is not fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `webClient.DownloadDataAsync` completes, it fires `DownloadDataCompleted` event, not `DownloadFileCompleted` - the one you registered.

The fix is, if you use `webClient.DownloadDataAsync`, register the `DownloadDataCompleted` event; Note that the 2nd argument to `webClient_DownloadDataCompleted` is different.

```
webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadDataCompleted);
```

...

```
private void webClient_DownloadDataCompleted(Object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{ 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed that particular problem!

Comment: So you mean there are other issues, could you get the `DialogResult` now?

Comment: There's other issues, but they're in different parts of the program. However, you've solved my initial question and the DialogResult and the ShowDialogue thing are working now! Thank you so much!